# Lyx 2.1 RC1, warning message "the selected document class Article" requires external files

Tags: lyx

I just installed  2.1 RC1 bundle on windows 7

Each time I try to save a document (also when I first open Lyx), I get this message

[image]

LyX-210RC1-Bundle-1.exe

why this happens? Do I need to configure something else? I had Lyx 2.0 before, but I uninstalled that before installing Lyx 2.1

Comment: This should not happen. Please send an email to lyx-users@lists.lyx.org describing the problem. There have been a couple issues reported and a few new installers released. For example you could try https://sourceforge.net/projects/lyxwininstaller/files/TestVersions/LyX-210RC1-Installer-3.exe/download but note that it is experimental, unofficial, and should not be trusted. It is, however, made by the main LyX developer of the Windows installer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also got this message. For me, this is what I think was going on:

The first execution of Lyx very quietly (i.e., in the background) performs package updates for MiKTeX. Afterwards, it actually launches Lyx.

However, if you launch a second invocation of Lyx immediately after the first (since nothing has yet displayed), it will launch w/o the packages it requires and result in the message that you see.

I suppose if MiKTeX was not / improperly installed, you could also encounter this issue.

Answer (score 1):

@scottkosty is right--this should not happen and having downloaded the latest version of LyX 2.1.1. I had the same problem (NOTE: I am, however, working on a Mac). These are the steps I took to finally get things working in my case:

If you have the above issues working on a Mac with OS X try the following:

```
1. reinstall latest version MacTeX at: [https://tug.org/mactex/][1]
2. install latest version of LyX: 2.1.1. (see: [http://www.lyx.org/Download][2])
3. Tools --> Reconfigure. 
4. Restart, check: Document --> Settings --> Document Classes: these should now be available.
```

Answer (score 0):

i had a similar problem but I believe I sorted it. If you can get someone to send you their 'templates' folder (i just put my one from my old laptop on googledrive), then go to lyx, go preferences, go paths, and then set the path to go to the location of your new templates folder. I then restarted it and it worked! Hope it helps :)